# Bash command with backticks inside of xargs

Tags: linux, bash, xargs

```
  echo $TMPLIST | xargs -I{} -n 1 -P $MAXJOBS curl -o {}_$DATESTRING.dump `get-temp-url --location {}`
```

$TMPLIST has a list of locations which I want processed.
I am trying to run something similar to the above, but the brackets inside of the backticks do not get expanded. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why doing something this complicated? What about looping through it in a way that is more readable?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming'  this kind of `xargs` usage is among the most concise ways of parallel processing (note the `-P` argument).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this command...

```
echo $TMPLIST | 
xargs -I{} -n 1 -P $MAXJOBS curl -o {}_$DATESTRING.dump \
  `get-temp-url --location {}`
```

...the backtics are interpreted *by the shell*; they are never seen by `xargs`.  You could do something like this:

```
echo $TMPLIST | 
xargs -I{} -n 1 -P $MAXJOBS \
  sh -c 'curl -o {}_$DATESTRING.dump `get-temp-url --location {}`'
```

Note that for this to work, `DATESTRING` will need to be an environment variable, rather than a shell variable (e.g., you would need to `export DATESTRING`).

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the warning about making the variable an ENVAR too.